# Jqueryを使って、ソート機能を実装しようとしているのですが、別の書き方を模索しています。

Tags: jquery

Jqueryを使って、別の書き方を模索しています。
現在ソート機能を下記のやり方で実装したいと思っています。
個人的には今書いてあるものでも行けると思っているのですが、下記の要素を使った際だとどのような実装になるのか勉強させていただきたいです。
.show() 要素を表示させる
.hide() 要素を隠す
.val() 要素のvalueを取得
.data('') DOM要素にあるdata-~を取得できる
.change() セレクトボックスの値の変更をキャッチする関数
$().each() DOM要素を1つずつループ処理をする（ループ内で$(this)を使うと要素がひとつずつ取得できる）

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<title>jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../common/css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../common/css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents">
    <p class="title">Frameworks</p>
    <div class="select-wrapper">
      <select class="select">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="css">CSS</option>
        <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="php">PHP</option>
        <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
        <option value="python">Python</option>
        <option value="scala">Scala</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li data-category-type="css">
        <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-bootstrap"></i>
          <p class="article-name">Bootstrap</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-category-type="ruby">
        <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-ruby-on-rails"></i>
          <p class="article-name">Ruby on Rails</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-category-type="php">
        <a href="https://phalconphp.com/ja/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-phalcon"></i>
          <p class="article-name">Phalcon</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-category-type="javascript">
        <a href="https://facebook.github.io/react/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-react"></i>
          <p class="article-name">React</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-category-type="scala">
        <a href="https://www.playframework.com/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-play"></i>
          <p class="article-name">Play</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-category-type="javascript">
        <a href="http://aurelia.io/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-aurelia"></i>
          <p class="article-name">Aurelia</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-category-type="python">
        <a href="http://djangoproject.jp/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-django"></i>
          <p class="article-name">Django</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-category-type="css">
        <a href="http://www.material-ui.com/#/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-material-ui"></i>
          <p class="article-name">Material UI</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-category-type="php">
        <a href="https://laravel.com/" class="article">
          <i class="article-icon is-laravel"></i>
          <p class="article-name">Laravel</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="../../common/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".select").on('change',function(){
    var v=$(this).val();
    $('ul.list li').toggle(v=="All").filter('[data-category-type='+v+']').show();
  }).trigger('change');
});





.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
.contents {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.title {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.select-wrapper {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.select {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.list > li {
  border-top: 1px #eee solid;
}
.article {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.article-icon {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.article-icon.is-bootstrap { background-image: url(../img/bootstrap.png); }
.article-icon.is-material-ui { background-image: url(../img/material-ui.png); }
.article-icon.is-react { background-image: url(../img/react.png); }
.article-icon.is-aurelia { background-image: url(../img/aurelia.png); }
.article-icon.is-ruby-on-rails { background-image: url(../img/ruby-on-rails.png); }
.article-icon.is-laravel { background-image: url(../img/laravel.png); }
.article-icon.is-phalcon { background-image: url(../img/phalcon.png); }
.article-icon.is-django { background-image: url(../img/django.png); }
.article-icon.is-play { background-image: url(../img/play.png); }
.article-name {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: `.show()`と`.val()`は既に使っていますよね？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あまりスマートじゃないですが、とりあえず全部使うと以下のような感じでしょうか。
尚、適当なサンプルだからだと思いますが、selectにはidつけてidで参照したほうが事故を未然に防げます。（念のため）

```
$(function() {
  $(".select").change(function(){ // .change()使用
    var v=$(this).val(); // .val()使用
    if(v=="all"){
      $('ul.list li').each(function(){ $(this).show() }); // .each()使用
    } else {
      $('ul.list li').each(function(){
        if($(this).data("category-type")==v){ // .data()使用
          $(this).show(); // .show()使用
        } else {
          $(this).hide(); // .hide()使用
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```